# Numerical solutions to wave equation

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Does the wave equation always have an analytical solution given well-behaved boundary/initial conditions? If not, under what conditions does the wave equation need to be solved numerically?  [This figure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aWave_equation_1D_fixed_endpoints.gif) of a simple 1D-problem seems to have been generated numerically.

Any recommended reading for general theory on the wave equation is also welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Derivation](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~feldman/apps/wave.pdf)

[Solutions](http://web.mit.edu/fluids-modules/waves/www/material/chap-2.pdf)

It has a general solution but numerical solutions can still be an interesting exercise. Numerical solutions are useful when you are solving some variation of the wave equation with an additional term in it which makes it unsolvable analytically.

Comment: Thanks sav.  So the solution shown here (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aWave_equation_1D_fixed_endpoints.gif) has an analytical expression?

Comment: I think one way to get the solution is to 

1: Laplace transform the equation

2: include boundary conditions

3: Turn the result into an ODE

4: Solve the ODE using method of undetermined coefficients

5: Use inverse Laplace transform to get back to original solution.


Also an interesting note: the derivation of the wave equation includes an approximation of wave behavior so a 'true' solution may still have limitations

Answer (score 0):

Stein & Shakarchi introduction to Fourier analysis is also a good reference, where the theory of wave equations is well developed, a main tool to find solutions is the Fourier transfom.